# Better way to specify different FieldConstructor for different form fields?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am using Play framework 2 and forms with Bootstrap 3 and so need to change the markup around an input element on a field by field basis. I have read the answers about creating and specifying different FieldConstructor values for each field but this seems over complicated and is harder for frontend developers/designers to understand. So I am looking for a more straightforward way.

So far I have been able to create a helper that lets me define the FieldConstructor template inline:

`views/helper/forms/customField.scala.html`

```
@(createElement: (views.html.helper.FieldConstructor) => Html)(template: (views.html.helper.FieldElements) => Html)
@createElement(
    views.html.helper.FieldConstructor(template)
)
```

I can then do this in each view:

```
@customField(implicit fc => helper.inputText(loginForm("email"),
    'id -> "txtEmail", 'placeholder -> "Email address"
)) { f =>
    <div class="form-group @if(f.hasErrors) {has-error}">
        <label class="sr-only" for="@f.id">Email address</label>
        @f.input
        @if(f.hasErrors){
            <div class="help-block"> @f.errors.mkString(", ")</div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Is there a better way to do this so I can reduce some of the mess in the second block? Are there any problems with this sort of approach e.g. in terms of performance, such as from recreating the FieldConstructor each time the form is rendered?